# Postfix - TLS - Port 587 - Connects only from localhost

Tags: postfix

**Why am I unable to connect to Postfix on port 587 on an AMI?**

This is an AMI, the AMI firewall has 587 open, iptables is empty because I am using the Amazon firewall.

From the server itself the following works fine:

> openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect ami.example.com:587

**postconf -n**

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 9
debug_peer_list = ami.example.com mail.example.com
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**master.cf**

```
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

**nmap** results

```
Nmap scan report for ami.example.com 
Host is up (0.024s latency).

Not shown: 995 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
143/tcp open   imap
587/tcp closed submission
993/tcp open   imaps
```

**netstat** results

```
netstat --proto=inet -pnl | grep 587
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587  0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    29829/master
```

Results when using from a remote machine:

> openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect ami.example.com:587
>
> socket: Connection refused
>
> connect:errno=111

Authentication is by pam.

Checked: [Postfix Refused on 587](https://serverfault.com/questions/651960/postfix-refused-on-587)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have inet_interfaces set to localhost. You can see the effect of this in your netstat output, where the process is only listing on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Changing inet_interfaces to **all** resolved the issue.  Thank you.